# error while setting variants option array Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

hello iam creating an ecomerce shop in my chec dasboard i set variants of sizes large small but when i try to implement options drop down on options array i get the error Cannot read property '0' of undefined in line12 which is let finalSizeArray = props.product.variants[0].options.map(option =

productcard.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Card, Image, Button, Icon, Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const ProductCard = (props) => {
     console.log(props.product, 'props from Container')

    const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([])
    const [variantInfo, setVariantInfo] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {        
        
       let finalSizeArray = props.product.variants[0].options.map(option => {
            let sizeInfo = {}

           sizeInfo.key = option.name
           sizeInfo.text = option.name
           sizeInfo.value = option.id

            return sizeInfo
        })

        setSizes(finalSizeArray)
    }, [])

    const handleSize = (e, {value}) => {
        setVariantInfo({[props.product.variants[0].id]: value})
    }

    const handleButtonAddCart = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        props.addToCart(props.product.id, variantInfo)
        
        
        // Funtion to Clear Select Input for Dropdown - Needs work. 
        // let selectInput = document.querySelectorAll('.sizes-drop')
        // selectInput.forEach((input,i) => {
        //     input.children[0].innerHTML = 'Select Size'
        //     // input.children[0].classList.add('default')
        // })
    }

    return (
        <Card>
            <Image src={props.product.media.source} />
            <Card.Content>
                <Card.Header>{props.product.name}</Card.Header>
                <Card.Meta>{props.product.price.formatted_with_symbol}</Card.Meta>
                <Card.Description>{props.product.description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")}</Card.Description>
                <Dropdown
                    className="sizes-drop"
                    
                    
                   fluid
                   placeholder='Select Size'
                   selection
                   options={sizes}
                />
                <Button fluid className='add-button' onClick={handleButtonAddCart}>
                    Add to Cart
                    <Icon name='arrow right' />
                </Button>
            </Card.Content>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Comment: Is props.product.variants an array and is there an element with the index 0 given?

Comment: Seems that either `props.product.variants` is undefined, you can't access the 0'th element of an array that doesn't exist. Can you update your question to include the parent component code that is providing the `props.product.variants` prop?

Comment: i  dont have props.product.variants anywhere else in the code

Comment: for reference i was following this tutorial exactly as it is in the repo https://github.com/kingmoc/adding-products-cart-cjs-react

Comment: "i dont have props.product.variants anywhere else in the code" It doesn't need to be used anywhere else to still be undefined, but you've at least ***two*** references right in this code snippet. We're referring to it being passed as a prop. ***Some*** parent component is passing `product` as a prop to the component in your snippet and for at least 1 render cycle (likely the initial render) `product.variants` is undefined. It looks like `ProductCard ` is rendered by `ProductContainer`. Can you log the `products` state value once it's populated?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its because your props not yet loaded...
You can give handle to your code like this

```
useEffect(() => {        
   let finalSizeArray = props?.product?.variants[0]?.options?.map(option => {
      let sizeInfo = {}

      sizeInfo.key = option.name
      sizeInfo.text = option.name
      sizeInfo.value = option.id

      return sizeInfo
   })

   setSizes(finalSizeArray)
}, [])
```

Comment: This is a band-aid fix, at least wait to see what the cause of the issue is to see if there is a better, more optimal solution.

Comment: i was refering to https://github.com/kingmoc/adding-products-cart-cjs-react